# How to keep my change in local branch without impacting remote repository by GIT?

Tags: git

I `git clone` a repository, then made some change in the local. Now I need to pull content from remote master branch, but 1) I want to keep my changes in local; 2) I don't want to push my changes to remote master branch.

I think I can create a local branch, and commit my changes to the local branch, then make sure to not push the local branch to remote.

But I'm new to GIT, I just have the idea, but I'm not clear how to implement this idea. Could anybody give a brief procedure with some real git command lines?

Comment: Pull does git fetch && git merge. I.e. it downloads changes from the remote and merges with your history, thus your commits stay in your history. And if you don't want to push your changes, don't do it... (am I missing something here? requirement 2) seems pretty trivial to me).
Depending on your workflow you could consider to use git pull --rebase to keep your local branches up to date.

Comment: I might forget to mention that I don't want to merge. I just want to pull complete master branch to my local again, and keep my previous changes in a separate local branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think I can create a local branch, and commit my changes to the
>   local branch, then make sure to not push the local branch to remote.

That is how you should do it. You should never do work directly in your `master` branch. The key to using git is not reverting to obscure hash codes—you only deal with that nightmare when the things really, really, really go awry—but creating branches to do work isolated from the `master` branch.

Just do this:

```
git checkout -b develop
```

That will create a new branch called `develop` that you can use for isolated development from he `master` branch.

You can push, pull & commit without issue or conflicts.

And when you are done doing your work on `develop` then you can merge your changes into master like this.

```
git checkout master
```

Now do a `git pull` to make sure `master` is up to date. And then merge.

```
git merge --no-ff develop
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you can do:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

This way, you keep your local changes. Of course this is useful if you have made some changes and haven't commited them to your local repository.

And as @skorgon mentioned in the comment, #2 is trivial.